# Screen scraper for creating a log of gathering in a RPG

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, screen-scraping, ocr

I want to create a program that can log gathering in a RPG for me, the problem is that I dont know where to start. I know c++ and some c#, but I haven't got a clue on how to scan the screen.

What I've looked at:

- Screen scraping (most info is on scraping HTML pages)
- OCR (Most info
  is on OCR on a image file, not an active window)
- Spy++ (I haven't got
  a clue)

I can do it with any language, but I'd prefer c++ or c# since that what I'm most experienced in

What is the best way to do it? anyone got some helpful links/tips?

**example of something I'd like to know (amongst other things):**

Would it be wise to make a screenshot like once every seccond and then analyze that image?

Should I learn and use windows API for this?

**before you bash me:**

- Yes, I know that this will be a big project, nothing I expect to complete easily
- Yes, I understand that I will have to learn more about programming to do this (that's part of the goal)
- Yes, I understand that it might be more than I can handle at my current level of skill, but I'd like to figure that out by trying :)

Please help me, I really dont have a clue about where to start

Comment: When you say "log gathering", do you literally mean picking up logs in this game, or reading the RPG log?
Also could you be a tad more specific.
Not to be a jerk but: SO is not a link farm (just trying to help your question get answered ;-) ).

Comment: I mean for example creating a XML logfile (from info on the screen) that stores for example the name of the node, the coordinates and the time

Comment: Why would you like to go through the trouble of scanning a screenshot with all its trouble (occlusion, distortions, ...) when you could try to spy on the memory of e.g. the inventory?

Comment: That's an example of something I didn't know, memory reading/spying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are serious about creating this program I would suggest you forget about scanning the screen, image analysis gets very complicated very quickly.

Instead look into memory reading, the information shown in the game can also be read as a straight up value from the games working memory.

There are probably resources out there for your game already, google it.

[World of Warcraft](https://www.google.com/search?q=wow%20memory%20address)

[Diablo 3](https://www.google.com/search?q=diablo%203%20memory%20address)

etc